# Inner Transaction is not rolling back (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, transactions

I have a DAO class which creates a new transaction. My JUnit test has its own transaction which I have set to rollback after the test is executed. Now whats happening is the outer transaction rolls back but the inner one does not.

Here is my DAO class(BookDaoImpl) which creates a new transaction.

```
@Component("bookDaoImpl")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,rollbackFor=DatabaseAccessException.class) 
public class BookDaoImpl implements BookDao {
    ....
    ....
  }
```

here is my JUnit test class(BookDaoImplTest).

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:com/shubham/spring/config/dao-context.xml"})
public class BookDaoImplTest {



    @Autowired
    private BookDao bookDao;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(true)
    public void test() {

    Book book=new Book();
    book.setAuthor("abc");
    book.setBookTitle("bookTitle");
    book.setCopiesAvailable(3);
    book.setImageName("abc.jpg");
    book.setPublisher("publisher");
try {
    bookDao.createBook(book);
} catch (DatabaseAccessException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

       assertTrue("books greater than 0",bookDao.getAllBooks().size()>0);
    }

}
```

Now I want the inner transaction to rollback as well with the outer transaction but it is not rolling back. And I have to create a new transaction (REQUIRES_NEW) at dao layer due to some conditions.

Suggest me the way out to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What is your reasoning for the test case being transactional? It's not really needed.

Comment: I want the Effects of test to rollback on database, that is why performing them in transaction.